# Orchestra Testbench current route always return null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm working on a Laravel package it is working when I use it in my Laravel project, but when I want to test it with **Orchestra Testbench** I always get current route null inside middlware.

Test directory on Github: https://github.com/yoeunes/larafast/tree/master/tests

**Base TestCase:**

```
class TestCase extends Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase
{
    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        $kernel = app('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

        $kernel->pushMiddleware(\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class);
        $kernel->pushMiddleware(\Yoeunes\Larafast\Middlewares\BlacklistRoutes::class);
    }
}
```

**WebControllerTest:**

```
class WebControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */
        $router = $this->app['router'];

        $router->resource('lessons', 'Yoeunes\Larafast\Tests\Stubs\Controllers\Web\LessonController');
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_show_create_page()
    {
        /** @var TestResponse $response */
        $response = $this->call('get', '/lessons/create');
        dd($response);
        $response->assertSuccessful();
        $response->assertSee('<title>lessons create |  Larafast</title>');
        $response->assertSee('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> lessons create');
        $response->assertSee('<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/lessons" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    }
}
```

**BlacklistRoutes Middleware:**

```
class BlacklistRoutes
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd(app('router')->getCurrentRoute()); // always get null
        if (null !== ($route = app('router')->getCurrentRoute())
            && is_a($controller = $route->getController(), Controller::class)
            && in_array($route->getActionMethod(), $controller->getBlacklist(), true)) {
            throw new BlacklistRouteException();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Orchestra Testbench Github repository :

> AFAIK global middleware is resolved before route is resolved,
> therefore getCurrentRoute() shouldn't be available yet.

So to resolve my problem I can access the current route from within the controller constructor like this:

```
public function __construct() 
{ 
    $this->middleware(function ($request, Closure $next) { 
        if (null !== ($route = app('router')->getCurrentRoute())
            && is_a($controller = $route->getController(), Controller::class)
            && in_array($route->getActionMethod(), $controller->getBlacklist(), true)) {
              
            throw new BlacklistRouteException();
        }
    }); 
}
```